# Gravity underground on the moon?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, planets, moon

They say that gravity Decreases as we dig into the earth.  But I also read that gravity increases for the first approx. 2000km of distance underground.  Using this rational, could we dig about 200 to 500 metres underground on the moon or Mars for an increase in gravity??...put another way..does the extreme increase in the surrounding mass of a cavity or air pocket provide more gravity??

Answer (score 2):

> They say that gravity decreases as we dig into the earth.

That's an immediate consequence of an overly simplistic model of the Earth, that the Earth is of a uniform density throughout. This is very far from the case.

> But I also read that gravity increases for the first approx. 2000km of distance underground

Actually, it's about 2900 km underground, not 2000. That's where the rock that forms the crust and mantle change to the iron and nickel that forms the Earth's core. That represents a very sharp change in density. Gravitational acceleration increases with increasing depth of the local density is less than 2/3 of the average density of all the stuff inside that point. It decreases if the local density is at least 2/3 of that average density.

There are a number of phase and composition transitions inside the Earth. The most marked of these is the transition from rock to metal at the core/mantle boundary. The same applies to the Moon; it too has a metallic core surrounded by a rocky mantle and crust.

> Put another way..does the extreme increase in the surrounding mass of a cavity or air pocket provide more gravity?

Assuming you aren't carving away half the planet (or moon) to make a hole to the center, the answer is no. The little pockets creates by digging even a monstrous machine-sized hole are tiny compared to the planet (or moon) as a whole. It's the density of all the stuff underfoot versus the density of the stuff through which you are digging that counts.

Comment: If you want, I'll add a derivation of that 2/3 figure.

Answer (score 0):

The local gravitational field increases (slightly) as you descend under the earth because much of the earths mass is in the core, and you're getting closer to the core.

As the moon has a smaller core, this effect would be reduced.  Even on earth, the effect is not really noticeable at depths we can dig to.

So the effect may not be present on the moon, and it would be a tiny effect if it were there.

This graphic gives an idea of the amount that the strength would change on the earth.
[image]

Comment: Deepest humans have gone is [12,000 m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kola_Superdeep_Borehole), which is 0.012 in 1000 km.